# what does anacron anacrontab delay in minutes and RANDOM_DELAY actually do?

Tags: cron

The manual says:

```
       The delay in minutes variable specifies the number of minutes anacron waits, **if**
       **necessary**, before executing a job.  This variable is represented by an  integer
       where 0 means no delay.
```

```
       The  RANDOM_DELAY  variable  denotes the maximum number of minutes that will be
       added to the delay in minutes variable which is specified for each job.  A RAN‐
       DOM_DELAY  set to 12 would therefore add, randomly, between 0 and 12 minutes to
       the delay in minutes for each job in that particular anacrontab.  When  set  to
       0, no random delay is added.
```

What does "if necessary" mean? Does this mean, if my /etc/anacrontab entry is:

```
1       5       cron.daily              nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
```

that cron.daily is run five minutes after 3 am (if the system is up at 3) always, or does it mean it runs 5 minutes after every hour only if some conditions are met?
If

```
RANDOM_DELAY=45
```

does this always delay the execution of cron.daily by 0-45 minutes (inclusive)? If so, is that on top of the 5 minutes? Or do some conditions need to be met before RANDOM_DELAY is applied as with the 5 minutes delay?

Answer (score 0):

/var/lib/logrotate/logrotate.status shows when logrotate was actually run. This demonstrates the RANDOM_DELAY is always in effect. The "delay in minutes" delays the onset of that random delay. This field is required because in /etc/anacrontab START_HOURS_RANGE=3-22 is defined. This only specifies the hour to start at, 3 am if the system is up. The "delay in minutes" field being set to 5 starts the job at 3:05, not 3. However the random delay of 0-45 minutes (inclusive, I believe) is added to 3:05, so the actual start range is 3:05-3:50 (if the system is up at that time). If the system is temporarily down at that time, the job can start anywhere in the range 3:05 - 22:50 depending on when the system goes back online.